# How to make Cycle(JQuery plugin) slider only images, not Div tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-cycle

How to make Cycle(JQuery plugin) slider only images, not Div tags

for example:

```
<div id="banner">
 <img />
 <img />
 <img />

<div class="description">

</div>


</div>
```

I want only to slide the img tags, not the div of description block

Comment: Cycle is designed to grab everything inside the containing element. Your solution should be to take the `.description` out of the `.banner`.

Comment: Cycle doesn't have a built-in way to target only specific children, it selects them all instead. The better solution would be to simply place the .description div somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you still need this, but I recommend upgrading to [Cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/). It should largely be a drop-in replacement, and Cycle2 has the "slides" property, which allows you to select the child elements that you want made into slides (which defaults to the direct image children of the container you put `.cycle()` on).